# Formatting an array of lambdas in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, lambda, visual-studio-2019

I would like Visual Studio (16.9.5) to auto-format C++-code with lambdas inside an array like this:

```
static S o[] = {
    {"tag1", [](const D* a , SGD& data)->void {
            if (a != 0) {
                data.a = a;
            }
        }
    },
    {"tag2", [](const D* a , SGD& data)->void {
            if (a != 0) {
                data.a = a;
            }
        }
    },
    ...
};
```

Other variants may be considered, provided they are consistent between tag1 and tag2.

Full example with current auto-formatting in Visual Studio 2019 to show what I don't want:

```
struct SGD { const D* a; };
struct D;

typedef void (*SGDFunc)(const D*, SGD&);
struct S {
    const char* n;
    SGDFunc func;
};
static S o[] = {
    {"tag1", [](const D* a , SGD& data)->void {
        if (a != 0) {
            data.a = a;
        }
}
    },
{"tag2", [](const D* a , SGD& data)->void {
    if (a != 0) {
        data.a = a;
    }
}
},
};
```

The code above is simplified, but the main idea is to use this to perform different operations based on string-tags.

Is there some style-setting that accomplishes this? Or some variant of the formatting?

Comment: Maybe change to select `Block` in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Tabs > Indenting can make it consistent between tag1 and tag2. Besides, since there are many nested conditions, if you choose some options to automatically format, usually the format will be a mess. Perhaps you can consider unchecking `Automatically format braces when they are automatically completed` option in C/C++ > Code Style > Formatting > General. Another style option maybe works for you: [Clang-Format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT  I tried, but I couldn't get that to work, and since most of the code isn't using lambdas in this way I don't want to turn off the usual Auto-Formatting (manually formatting this section is less pain).

Comment: Ok, then the format is hard to change. Some extensions maybe help, but not sure, you can search [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=format&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance).